# Azure ADF - ContentMD5 field in Get Metadata activity is always null

Tags: metadata, azure-data-factory

If I manually upload txt or csv files in azure blob storage, when using the get metadata activity, I always get "contentMD5": null, while the other fields of the output are always populated. I also tried to copy it from on prem to blob storage using azcopy,but I have same issue. I am using ADF v2.

screen shot here [null ContentMD5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrQD0.png)

Any idea why would this happen?
Thanks

Comment: the field list of the activity has the contentMD5 specified:       
                   
                     "fieldList": [
                        "columnCount",
                        "contentMD5",
                        "itemName",
                        "itemType",
                        "lastModified",
                        "size",
                        "structure"
                    ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, that's not the Data Factory error.

Please check the file property in your Blob Storage. I also have one file without content-MD5:

[image]

That why the result of get metadata contentMD5 will be null.

**How to solve this problem?**

I just download the `test.csv` to my computer,  delete it(Also delete blob snapshots) in the container. Then re-upload it, we can see the CONTENT-MD5 now:

[image]

Run the get metadata activity, check the out put:

[image]

Hope this helps.